# Showing injectivity of a map between the sum of Picard groups of projective smooth irrudicible curve and the Picard group of the product of the curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

I want to solve the following exercise:

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and consider a smooth projective irreducible curve $C$ over $k$. Set $S$ $:= C ×C$. Show that $p_{1}^* \oplus p^*_2 : \operatorname{Pic}(C)\oplus \operatorname{Pic}(C) \to \operatorname{Pic}(S)$ is injective, where $p_i : S \to C$ is the i-th projection.

I found a more general solution in the paper of [Ischebeck](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN266833020_0139&DMDID=DMDLOG_0022&LOGID=LOG_0022&PHYSID=PHYS_0151), but as I do not understand German, I find it very difficult to follow the demonstration. I would also like to demonstrate it, if possible, in a more direct manner.

I have tried to exploit the isomorphism that exists between $\operatorname{Pic}(C)$ and the class group of Weil's divisors $\operatorname{Cl}(C)$ and tried to reason as one does for the classical example of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, but without having a clear idea of how to continue, since even having an equivalence between $C$ minus a point and an affine space $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$, I do not know two things well:

1. How to show that indeed the ring $A$ on which the affine space is defined is a UFD, so that then $\operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Spec}(A))=0$, and;
2. Even having that I am not given any isomorphism between $\operatorname{Cl}(C \times \operatorname{Spec}(A))$ and $\operatorname{Cl}(C)\times \operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Spec}(A))$, as happens in the example.

Would you have any suggestions on how such an exercise could be carried out, without exploiting Ischebeck's result?

Comment: Let $i$ be the inclusion of $C\times p$ for some point  $p\in C$. Can you calculate the kernel of $i^*p_i^*$?

Comment: This maybe a direction, but I've never seen anyone mentioning it so it is probably not doable: by Kunneth formula, $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^*_X)\oplus H^1(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y^*) = H^1(X \times Y, pr_X^*\mathcal{O}_X^* \oplus pr_Y^*\mathcal{O}_Y^*)$ so we may think of $\Gamma(\mathcal{O}^*_{X \times Y}/pr_X^*\mathcal{O}_X^* \oplus pr_Y^*\mathcal{O}_Y^*, X \times Y)=0$.

Comment: @Mohan Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, but what do you mean by $p_i^*$?

Comment: @AlexeyDo in the course we didn't see the Kunneth formula, so i don't think it's the direction they ask for

Comment: @Lopi78, yes I just comment to see if it can go that way. In Ischebeck, varieties are just assumed to be normal, but here you have smoothness and projectiveness so it could be easier somehow. You might want to look at exercise 4.10 (solution avalable online) in Hartshorne where curves are elliptic but I think its proof can be carried over to your situation.

Comment: @AlexeyDo thank you I will have a look at that exercise. In Hartshorne “algebraic geometry”?

Comment: I am using your notation, $p_1^*$ and $p_2^*$.